# Trying to setup a personal ANS server. Not able to bind domain name

Tags: server, dns, namecheap

***Goal:***

My goal is to setup a web server and an ANS server for my website at home where it is publicly available. I can access the webpage through my public IP address outside of my network, but can't figure out how to bind that address with the domain name I purchased on namecheap.com.

***What I'm Running:***

I'm using
VirtualBox 6.0.4
; 3 guest machines that are running Ubuntu 18.10 (for a primary and secondary dns server and a web server)
; my host machine is running Windows 10
; bind9 for ANS (DNS) and apache2 as a web server
; and my domain name was purchased at namecheap.com

***What I've Done***:

I've followed the instructions on this page to setup the DNS servers : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-an-authoritative-only-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04

The network setting on VirtualBox(VB) is set to "bridged adapter."

On my router, I've opened (http) port 80 for the IP address of my apache web server and (tcp/udp) port 53 for the IP address of my primary DNS server.

***My questions:***

I'm unclear as to which IP addresses to put in at namecheap.com under "custom DNS"?? The IP addresses of my DNS servers in VB or the IP address of the DNS servers that is provided by my router? If it's the latter, then how do I add them to the named.conf files?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the public IP address of your router does not change, you should do port forwarding in the router for your VB to be accessed from the internet, then use your router's public IP to configure in namecheap.